# Are [online-learning] and [distance-learning] tags synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

While I was creating a post about distance learning, I noticed there were two different tags. One for online learning and one for distance learning. While distance learning covers a broader range (online, correspondence, etc.) online learning seems to always be distance learning and I suspect that most distance learning today is online. So, should we have two different tags for this?

Perhaps better to have a credit-learning and non-credit learning option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could imagine some edge cases where online learning is not distance learning. I think there are less cases of distance learning not being online nowadays.

I think the two tags might be useful since I would think that questions about on online-distance learning could often be divided into a distance or online question.

Comment: Agree: distance learning is a subset of online, but the reverse does not hold.

Comment: Then everything with an online tag should automatically get a distance tag? It seems like searching gets a little messy this way.

Comment: @earthling I don't think so. For example, a question about participating in online QA sessions would be online-learning. A question about establishing a relationship with a professor you never see would go under distance-learning.